# Bcrypt not installing on pycharm

Tags: installation, module, pip, pycharm, bcrypt

I wanted install flask bcrypt module it showed Error as .

Python implementation !="pypy" 'failed with error code 1 in none.
While installing Bcrypt

Comment: What have you exactly tried so far?

Comment: Jus wanted to install the said module